# How do you pass table as a parameter for a stored procedure using Slick?

Tags: sql-server, scala, stored-procedures, slick

What is the best practice to pass Tables into stored procedures from slick? Currently, my approach is to do the following, but I get this error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'App_Engage.dbo.retrieve_engage_geo_segment_id @Input'.

Here's the code:

In SQL, I created a Table type:

```
CREATE TYPE HotelInput AS TABLE(
    hotel_id INT,
    country_id INT
)
```

I also created a Stored Procedure using `HotelInput` table type as an input parameter as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sample_sp
    @input HotelInput READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- Do SQL Stuff operations to that table
END
```

Now, in my Scala application, I created some code to generate the `HotelInput` table in order to pass it as a parameter:

```
val inputData: Seq[(Int, Int, Int, Int)] = Seq(
    (1,2,3,4),
    (5,6,7,8)
)

val inputValues: String = inputData.map{input => input.productIterator.mkString("(", ",", ")")}.mkString("\n")
val inputQuery =
  s"""
    |DECLARE @Input HotelInput
    |VALUES
    |$inputValues""".stripMargin
```

Finally, I call the stored procedure and pass it the table I create:

```
database.run(sqlu"""$inputQuery + "exec App_Engage.dbo.retrieve_engage_geo_segment_id @Input""")
```

Where `database` is a JDBC Database instance (I am not including its assignment as it's irrelevant to the problem).